# Spring boot security - cannot add role and authorities together for inMemoryAuthentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

This is my Configuration class, where is register the users and the url matchers.

```java
package com.example.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
                .authorities("API_TEST1","API_TEST2")
                .roles("ADMIN")
            .and().withUser("test")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("test1234"))
                .authorities("API_TEST1")
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/api/test1").hasAuthority("API_TEST1")
            .antMatchers("/api/test2").hasAuthority("API_TEST2")
            .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

For some reason the roles and authorities do not work together, they work when I disable one of them:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
                .authorities("API_TEST1","API_TEST2")
                .roles("ADMIN")
            .and().withUser("test")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("test1234"))
                .authorities("API_TEST1")
                .roles("USER");
    }
```

When I login with admin, admin I can enter the /admin section, but entering the api (api/test1 or api/test2) gives me a 403 error, while I should be able to enter both.

Here is my complete project:
https://github.com/douma/spring-security-exp

Comment: calling `roles` or `authorities` isn't an adder (it doesn't add to existing authorities) but assigns these authorities (so when you are calling `roles` it replaces them). Now roles are authorities to (Spring Security only knows about authorities) but are automatically prefixed with `ROLE_`. So using `authorities("API_TEST1", "API_TEST2", "ROLE_ADMIN")` should do the trick.

Comment: Yes this solved it for me, thanks